# Complete html5 platform game as a snippet

Tags: javascript, game, html5

I made a complete little platformer game as a code snippet.
The goal is to try to keep jumping on the enemies without touching the ground to increase score.
I used [Tad's Basic Game Objects](https://www.tabageos.com), an open source set of JavaScript classes.
What do you think of the code?

```js
(function() {
    let map = [ [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4],
                [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],
                [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],
                [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],
                [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],
                [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,3],
                [3,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,3],
                [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],
                [3,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,3],
                [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3] ];
    const characterSpriteSheet = "data:image/png;base64,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";
    let enemies = [];
    let score = 0; 

    class VeryQuickPlatformer extends tabageos.GameSkeleton {

      constructor() { 
        super(); 
        this.dontEstablishWorkers();
        this.initialConstruction({gWidth:160, gHeight:160, cameraWidth:160, cameraHeight:160, spriteSheetImage:characterSpriteSheet,controllerDivId:"cn", gameLoop:this.loop,gameScale:0, initializationSpecifics:this.setup, fullResetSpecifics:this.backToTitle});  
      }

      setup() { 
        this.startButton.innerHTML = "Click/Touch to Start";this.removeHUD();
        
        var cani = new tabageos.CanvasAnimation(this._image, this.charLayer,null,16,32,16,16);
        cani.defineAnimation("left", [3,1,2,1,3,1,2,1]); 
        cani.defineAnimation("right",[1,0,2,0,1,0,2,0]);
        cani.currentAnimation = "right";
        
        this.player = new tabageos.MapTraveler(16,32,16,16, map,cani,1,0,16,16,map.length,map[0].length,0);
        this.player._jumps = 1;
        this._cameraType = 2;
        window.console.clear();
        
        tabageos.BlitMath.drawSquaresFromPattern(this.display, map, 16, 16, {3:"#ffc8c8",0:"#c8c8c8",4:"#000000"}); 
        
        if(!this.getButton("exit")) { this.makeButton("exit",144,0,16,16,"tabageos.GameSkeleton.game.fullResetToTitle()","back to title"); }
        
        this.beforeStartGameLoop = function() { 
          this.appendButton("exit"); 
        } 
        
        while(enemies.length < 3) {
          enemies.push( new tabageos.MapTraveler(32 * enemies.length,144,16,16,map,null) );
        }
      };
      
      backToTitle() {
          this.removeButton("exit");
          score = 0;
      };
      
      loop(ts) {
        var btns = this.controller.buttons;
        this.player.move(btns.left,btns.right,btns.up,btns.down);
        
        if(this.player._veloc.x <= -1) this.player._canvasAnimation.currentAnimation = "left";
        if(this.player._veloc.x >= 1) this.player._canvasAnimation.currentAnimation = "right";
        this.player._canvasAnimation.matchPosition(this.player);
        if(this.player._veloc.x !=0) this.player._canvasAnimation.animate(.3);
        this.player._canvasAnimation.blit();
        
        for(var en of enemies) {
          if(en._pRight) en._veloc.x = -2;
          if(en._pLeft) en._veloc.x = 2;
          en.update();
          if(tabageos.GeometricMath.testForPointInCircle(this.player._pos, 8, en._pos)) {
            if(!this.player._grounded) { this.player._veloc.y -= 4;score += 1;break; }
          }
          this.charLayer.drawRect(en.getRectangle(),"#bbbbbb");
        }
        
        this.pixelType(16,16,"score: "+score+"");
      };

    }
    new VeryQuickPlatformer();
})();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tabageos/tabageos/tbgs_min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tabageos/tabageos/ControllerPad.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tabageos/tabageos/ControllerPad.css">

<div id="container" style="position:absolute;width:160px;height:160px">
  <div id="root" style="width:160px;height:160px"> </div>
  <div id="cn"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That seems to be a fun little library! In your code I would remove the `(function() {` IIFE function. If you need the code to be private you can change your JS file to a module `<script type="module" src="...">`. Also you don't need the `function` keyword when you define a method on a class. `setup() { .. } ` should be enough.

Comment: Yes that is cleaner, in this case the`(function() {` is helping to indent the map array properly, I can't seem to get it to indent right without that line now.